# pointer without a malloc

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
        struct stat *something;
        stat("/etc/profile", something);
        printf("%d\n", something->st_gid);
        free(something);
        return 0;
}
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

I learned [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138600/correct-use-of-stat-on-c) that I need to allocate memory using malloc, so I changed it to as below, and it works:

```
-       struct stat *something;
+       struct stat *something = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
```

In a prior but related exercise, I did not use a malloc, and it had worked. 
I am lost!
Why don't I need malloc for the line "***struct dirent *b;***" below?

Or, to rephrase, how can we know the payload is too much and to use malloc?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        if (argc != 2){
                printf("Error. Syntax: ls <somefolder> \n");
                return 1;
        }
        DIR *a = opendir(argv[1]) ;
        if (a == NULL){
                printf("error. cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
                return 1;
        }

        // - malloc question about this very next line
        struct dirent *b; 
        while (( b = readdir(a)) != NULL){
                printf("%s %lu\n", b->d_name, b->d_ino);
        }

        int closing = closedir(a);
        printf("in closing, status is %d\n", closing);
        return 0;
}
```

Newcomer to C, clueless too - please be gentle! :)

Comment: What does `readdir()` do?  It seems likely that it allocates memory for  the struct?

Comment: Use `structure stat something;` and pass `&something` to `stat()`.

Comment: @StephenDocy no, it most probably returns a pointer to a static variable. The man page states that you cannot use `free` on the return value of `readdir`.

Comment: regarding your 'prior exercise'  your code contained undefined behavior.  With undefined behavior, anything can happen, even the code can 'seem' to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with

```
struct stat *something;
stat("/etc/profile", something);
```

is that `something` is an uninitialized pointer pointing to nowhere, this yields
undefined behaviour as `stat` would write something on an invalid address.
With `malloc` you allocated memory for it and passed a pointer to that allocated
memory location to `stat` and that's why it worked.

But you don't need to use `malloc` for that, just don't declare `something` as a
pointer:

```
struct stat something;
stat("/etc/profile", &something); // <-- look at the usage of &
```

In `stat` you should use the `&`-operator which returns a pointer to
`something`.

In your other program

```
struct dirent *b; 
while (( b = readdir(a)) != NULL)
```

[`readdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) returns a pointer to a valid location, the function itself took
care of using a valid object and returning a pointer to it. However, you cannot
do `free(b)`:

> *[man readdir](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir)*
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, `readdir()` returns a pointer to a dirent structure. **(This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to `free(3)` it.)**

Comment: an uninitialized pointer pointing to nowhere, this yields undefined behaviour -- When main is called as 

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
..`

when/where is *argv initialized?

Comment: @struggling_learner `argv` is initialized by the system. `main` is the entry point of a C program, but in reality there are other functions that are executed first (functions that open `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, prepare the `argc` and `argv` variables). So when `main` is finally executed, it's guaranteed that argv` will point to a valid location.

Answer (score 2):

`readdir` returns a pointer to a `struct dirent`. Doing:
`b = readdir(a)` overwrites the value `b` with the new value returned by `readdir`.

So of `b` was previously initialized with allocated memory from a `malloc` call, that value has been overwritten and you now likely have a memory leak.

You might wonder then whether you need to call `free` on `b` after the `readdir` call. To answer that you have to consult your documentation. In this case, the answer is **no**.

From the documentation for `readdir`:

> On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure. (This
>   structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
        struct stat *something;
        stat("/etc/profile", something);
        printf("%d\n", something->st_gid);
        free(something);
        return 0;
}
```

Above code has multiple issues,

1. you are using `something` which is not pointing to a valid location, and
   again using it as a buffer to store information return by `stat()`.

> int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf);

`stat()` return information about a file, in the buffer pointed to by `statbuf`, so your `statbuf` (something) should be a valid buffer, with size enough to store information of file, i.e size of `struct stat`.

2. `free(something);`

**from free() man page**

if the argument passed to free() does not match a pointer earlier returned by a function in POSIX.1‐2008 that allocates memory as if by malloc(), or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free() or realloc(), the behavior is undefined.

Now coming to other code:

```
// - malloc question about this very next line
        struct dirent *b; 
        while (( b = readdir(a)) != NULL){
                printf("%s %lu\n", b->d_name, b->d_ino);
        }
```

let's explore `readdir()` a bit,

> struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp); The readdir() function returns a
>   pointer to a dirent structure representing the next directory entry in
>   the directory stream pointed to by dirp.  It returns NULL on reaching
>   the end of the directory stream or if an error occurred.

You see `readdir()` returns a pointer of `struct dirent` type which makes `b` in
`struct dirent *b` a valid pointer. That's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Normally any pointers whether its a `int *ptr` or `char *ptr` or `struct student *ptr`, it should have  `valid address` and valid address may be *dynamically allocated address* or *address of some variable*.

**Case 1** : `struct stat *something;` here `something` is pointer of `struct stat` type and its un-initialized.

when you do `stat("/etc/profile", something);` you are trying to store `/etc/profile` information into `something` which is un-initialized. Instead of this you should store the information of `/etc/profile` into address of `something`   or

```
struct stat info;
struct stat *something = &info;
stat("/etc/profile",something );
```

**Case 2** : `struct dirent *b;`  `b` is pointer of type `struct dirent`, it should also have valid address.
 `b = readdir(a);` `readdir` return value is assigned to `b`, so now you can perform `b->d_name` etc.

From the manual page of `readdir()`

> On  success,  readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure. 
>   (This
>          structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to  free(3)  it.)

Comment: Not sure how this answer adds anything to the answers already posted